# Prove that $|x|$ can be uniformly approximated in [-1,1] by polynomials?

Tags: approximation-theory

I know how to aproximate it, is it enough to actually aproximate it to prove it can be aproximated?

I just noticed there is a suggestion here at the end. Sorry for lateness

Do Taylor arround the funcion $f(t):=t\sqrt{1-t}$ and  $t\in [-1,1]$
Show that $f\in C^\infty$ in $[-1,1)$ and that its taylor serioes is uniformly convergent in compacts of $[-1,1)$
Its derivate tends to $\infty$ if $t\rightarrow +1$ but f is continuous, then it is uniformly continuous in $ [-1,+1]$.

Not sure which theorem or result should be used here.

Comment: Well... of course. If you want to prove something **can** be done, then *actually* doing it is one way of proving that. **But** you have to actually show you did it. In your case, you need to prove that you actually made an approximation.

Comment: because $\text{sign}(x)$ can be approximated at an arbitrary precision (on $[-1,1]$) by some polynomials.

Comment: @user1952009 Not uniformly on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @joséosorio Is your approximation uniform?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli : yes of course, that was left as the exercice (to see that it is an approximation in $L^p$ norm)

Comment: Added the suggestion of the source, any  coment on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Stone-Weierstrass theorem, since $|x|$ is continuous on a closed inteval, it can be approximated uniformly by polynomials. If you want an example of such an approximation of your function, you can use Berstein's polynoms :$$B_n(f)=\sum_{k=0}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$$

Comment: Oh you are right i got this

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to prove that the approximation you find is an approximation.